# lateinit property data has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, rx-java2

Gson Convertable data is not set in Recyclerview using Retrofit2 and rxjava2 then subscribe throughble  its Give Error:

```
UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property data has not been initialized
```

JSON data parsing by retrofit2 and rxjava2. when parsing GSON Data Converting GSon, rxjava2 Subscribe the data then  give lateinit property error and its not set in recyclerview.

MainActivity.kt

```
class Company : AppCompatActivity() {


    internal lateinit var api : APIInterface

    var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()



    internal lateinit var companyDialog : Dialog

    internal lateinit var adapter: CompanyAdapter

    internal lateinit var data : List<Company>

    internal lateinit var rvCompany : RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_company)

        companyDialog = Dialog(this)

        //companyAdapter = CompanyAdapter()


        btnSelectCompany.setOnClickListener{
            showCompanyPopupView()
        }



    }

    fun showCompanyPopupView(){
        companyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.compny_popup_screen)

         rvCompany  = companyDialog.findViewById(R.id.rvCompany)

        rvCompany.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvCompany.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?

        fetchData()
        companyDialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        companyDialog.show()
    }

    private fun fetchData(){

        val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient
        if (retrofit != null) {
            api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
        }
        compositeDisposable.add(api.getCompanyData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe ({ companyList-> displayData(data)
                },{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })

        )

    }


    private fun displayData(companyList: List<Company>) {


        adapter = CompanyAdapter(this,companyList)
        rvCompany.adapter = adapter

    }


}
```

CompanyAdapter.kt

```
class CompanyAdapter(internal var context: Context, internal var companyList: List<Company>)
    :RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.CompanyViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CompanyViewHolder {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item,p0,false)

        return CompanyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        return companyList?.size!!
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CompanyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

       // p0.rbButton.text = this!!.companyList?.get(p1)?.Cmp_Name
        p0.bindModel(companyList[p1])
    }

    inner class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val radioButton : RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbCompanyName)

        fun bindModel(company: Company){

            radioButton.text = company.Cmp_Name
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because you never initialize it (`data = ...`), but you access it in `{ companyList-> displayData(data) }`. This ignores the `companyList` you get from `subscribe`, which is probably not what you actually want.

Your code seems to overuse `lateinit` a lot. Use it when you *really* need it.

Comment: What is the solution to the exact OP?

Comment: To either call `data = <something>`, e.g. `data = listOf()` before they get the company list, or not to access it in the lambda. Which of them, can't be said without knowing what the asker actually wants the logic to be, which the question doesn't say. Of course, Kanchan's guesses are reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You are using un-initialised variable `data` in `displayData(data)` function. Rather pass companyList what you are getting from `subscribe` function as follows.

```
 private fun fetchData(){

        val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient
        if (retrofit != null) {
            api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
        }
        compositeDisposable.add(api.getCompanyData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe ({ companyList-> displayData(companyList)
                },{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })

        )

    }
```

Also you can save `companyList` which you've got in your `data` variable first, before using it to avoid the error. Doing so will help you use this `companyList` at some other place in class `Company` instead of just passing in function.

```
compositeDisposable.add(api.getCompanyData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe ({ companyList-> 
                        data = companyList
                        displayData(data)
                },{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })

        )
```

Comment: I see you don't need `data` variable at all, so simply remove its declaration 
`internal lateinit var data : List<Company>` 

And pass  


`.subscribe ({    displayData(it)  }`

Comment: above comment solution, give error - kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented in Adapter class